# How to login on wordpress webpage using stored mysql data?

Tags: wordpress

I want to have log in page in my word press website in that user can log in with their user id and password. But the thing is that i want manually enter user id and password into my SQL database. So they can just log in using user id and password on word press webpage. Thank you for helping this question.

Comment: YOU CAN ADD USERS IN WORDPRESS ADMIN..

Comment: how i add user login page in wordpress website for users ?

Comment: add a login link to your site.

Comment: So what is the problem with that?